# Include fields other than count in azure facet results?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

While faceting azure search returns the count for each facet field by default.How do I also get other searchable fields for every facet?

Ex When I facet for area , I want something like this.(description is a searchable field)

```
{
  "area": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "description": "Acrylics",
      "value": "ACR"
    },
    {
      "count": 1,
      "description": "Power",
      "value": "POW"
    }
 ]
}
```

Can someone please help with the extra parameters I need to send in the query?

Comment: The relation between the faceted field and the description in this case is 1:1, right? You can also make the description field facetable and use it.

Comment: Georgi's suggestion would work only if each facet returned a unique count.  In this case both facets have a count of one, so the description facet you wouldn't know which description goes with each area as the order is not guaranteed when the counts are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do this as there is no direct support for nested faceting in Azure search (you can upvote it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7035293-support-hierarchical-facets)).  To achieve the result you want you would need to store the data together as a composite value as described by [this workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-example-adventureworks-multilevel-faceting).